# jquery Validate Plugin Hide Error Message

Tags: jquery-plugins

I have a basic table with radio buttons. I have an onclick even in the "td" that checks the radio when the "td" is clicked. The error message does not hide when the "td" is clicked. It only hides when the actual button is clicked. Here's my code. Any ideas? I have the jquery files stored locally.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="jquery-latest.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#myform").validate({
            errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                    error.appendTo(element.parent("td").prev("td") );
            },
            debug:true
        })
    });

    </script>
</head>

<body>
<form id="myform" action="/login" method="post">
<table border="1">
<tr>
    <td width="30%">Attribute 1<br /></td>
        <td width="10%" onclick="$(this).find('input:radio').attr('checked','checked');" /><INPUT  type="radio" id="22121GRID" name="SPGRID_1" value="5" class="required"  /></td>
        <td width="10%" onclick="$(this).find('input:radio').attr('checked','checked');" /><INPUT  type="radio" id="22121GRID" name="SPGRID_1" value="4" class="required"  /></td>
        <td width="10%" onclick="$(this).find('input:radio').attr('checked','checked');" /><INPUT  type="radio" id="22121GRID" name="SPGRID_1" value="3" class="required"  /></td>
        <td width="10%" onclick="$(this).find('input:radio').attr('checked','checked');" /><INPUT  type="radio" id="22121GRID" name="SPGRID_1" value="2" class="required"  /></td>
        <td width="10%" onclick="$(this).find('input:radio').attr('checked','checked');" /><INPUT  type="radio" id="22121GRID" name="SPGRID_1" value="1" class="required"  /></td>
</tr>
<tr><td><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td></tr>
</table>
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you changing the checked through javascript, call `.valid()` method of validator.

You can use the following

```
<td width="10%" onclick="$(this).find('input:radio').attr('checked','checked').valid();" />            <INPUT  type="radio" id="22121GRID" name="SPGRID_1" value="5" class="required"  /> </td>
```

or

```
$('td').click(function(){
$(this).find('radio').attr('checked','checked').valid();
});
```